# Does it ever make sense to overload unary operator &?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

So, C++ allows overloading the unary `operator &`(address). Are you aware of any ***real-world*** example when `operator &` was rightfully overloaded? And a second, more specific question, are you aware of any ***real-world*** example when `operator &` was rightfully overloaded while preserving address semantics? TIA

Comment: @Johannes: Thanks! I never knew about google code search. It's a pity I can't accept a comment as the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got 207 **real-world** examples of `operator &()`: [Code search 1](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22operator+%26%28%29%22&sbtn=Search), [Code search 2](http://www.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&lr=&q=%22operator+%26+%28%29%22&sbtn=Search).

Including [`SafeInt<>`](http://safeint.codeplex.com/) (to get the underlying naked integer), [boost::gil](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html) (apparently also to yield the raw data), Mozilla (that say "it is risky to define operator&, but, hey, we know what we're doing."), wxWidgets, [Armagetron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armagetron) and lots of more.

It seems some use the iterator idiom `&*it` to get a raw reference or pointer backwards, and write `*&it` to get a raw reference and `&it` to get a raw pointer.

Notice that once your type overloads `operator&` and returns something different than the built-in operator, your type is not CopyConstructible anymore (in C++03 - C++0x seems to have lifted it), and so cannot be used as element-type in a Standard container anymore.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be used in ATL, e.g http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s6et3yb.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a concrete example off-hand, but I could imagine a container class where you might want to return a smart pointer or an iterator.  I'm not saying this necessarily makes sense, though.

Comment: my question was -specifically- about real-world examples

Comment: You're right Oli. Smart pointer are classes which have to behave like pointers and thus need operators * or even & overloaded. Bang on.

Comment: @Samrat: What on earth does overloading & for a smart-pointer give you?!

Comment: If it doesn't make any sense please point that out. Although, I'm for sure, operator* is overloaded in smart pointer classes. This is the best scenario I can come up with for operator& :)

Comment: @Samrat: I imagine that works, but it's slightly annoying semantically.  Consider that `*&pObj` doesn't get you back to where you started!

Comment: @Samrat: With the same logic one must overload operator& for ANY proxy obect, including iterators... which I hope you agree is insane. And Oli's argument is pretty strong too

Comment: Actually, to be fair, `std::vector<T> v; &*v.begin();` doesn't get you back to where you started, either!

Answer (score 1):

One good reason to overload it might be to make it `private`, to prevent users from using it. I can't this think of any real-world example where you would want to prevent this, but it seems to be the most logical reason to overload it.

Answer (score 1):

I did it once when an object had a special-purpose smart pointer. `operator&` quietly 'lifted' a stack-allocated object into a heap-based smart pointer version, and this operator behaved differently once the object was inside the pointer.

I don't have the code any more, but there *was* a reason for it at the time. It's certainly not a decision to take lightly, this road is lined with corpses.

Answer (score 0):

I overloaded this operator when writing classes for interacting with Direct3D. It was a smart pointer class that needed to have T** returned from operator& so that it could be used in functions that expect pointer-to-pointer. T** semantics are rare but you do need them in some situations.