# Any difference between `auto* p = &n` and `auto p = &n`?

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, coding-style, auto

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int n;

    auto* p1 = &n;
    auto  p2 = &n;

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(p1), decltype(p2)>); // ok
}
```

Any difference between `auto* p = &n` and `auto p = &n`? or just a coding style issue?

Comment: style, readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any difference between `auto* p = &n` and `auto p = &n`?

No difference.

> or just a coding style issue?

Yes, for some it may be clearer with `auto* p1 = &n;` that it's a pointer.

Note, however, the [cpp core guideline](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r22-use-make_shared-to-make-shared_ptrs) seems to favour later/simpler style `auto  p2 = &n;` perhaps because it's consistent with the usage of smart pointer - which doesn't need any `*` to start with, example:

```
auto p = make_shared<X>(2);
```

Comment: There is indeed no difference if `n` is an `int`, but there are differences in general. See @peter.

Answer (score 4):

> Any difference between `auto* p = &n` and `auto p = &n`? or just a coding style issue?

In your example, where `n` is an `int`, the difference is coding style.

However, if `n` is an instance of a `struct` or `class` type, that provides a unary `operator&()`, then there is a difference.   `auto *p = &n` will be diagnosed as an error if that overloaded `operator&` returns any non-pointer type.   `auto p = &n` will only be diagnosed as an error if the `operator&()` returns `void`.    This can be useful (in the sense that it is better for the compiler to diagnose problems early) if subsequent code relies on `&n` giving a pointer.

Admittedly, overloading `operator&()` is a relatively rare (and risky) use case, and overloading to return a non-pointer type is quite rare.   However, real-world examples are given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948663/does-it-ever-make-sense-to-overload-unary-operator) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495977/what-legitimate-reasons-exist-to-overload-the-unary-operator).